# Maven wsdl2java <wsdlLocation> tag

Tags: java, maven, wsdl, wsdl2java, artifacts

I am using wsdl2java in a maven project to generate some artifacts. I didn't start from scratch, but inherited the work of my predecessors. I have a question related to the  tag in my pom file.

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
  <artifactId>cxf-codegen-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.1.4</version>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>generate-sources</id>
      <phase>generate-sources</phase>
      <configuration>
        <sourceRoot>${project.build.directory}/generated/cxf</sourceRoot>
        <wsdlOptions>
          <wsdlOption>
            <wsdlLocation>http://localhost:8080/sunrise/sunrise?wsdl</wsdlLocation>
            <wsdl>${basedir}/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/wsdl/sunrise/sunrise.wsdl</wsdl>
          </wsdlOption>
        </wsdlOptions>
      </configuration>
      <goals>
        <goal>wsdl2java</goal>
      </goals>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

What I am specifically interested in, is inside `<wsdlOptions>`. What is the difference between `<wsdlLocation>` and `<wsdl>`? Which one is used to generate artifacts from?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`<wsdlLocation>`](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/wsdl-to-java.html) specifies the value of the @WebServiceClient annotation's wsdlLocation property.

[`<wsdl>`](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/maven-cxf-codegen-plugin-wsdl-to-java.html) specifies the WSDL location in your project directories.